# C lang task - how to optimize my code for performance. My time complexity is O(N^2)

Tags: c, performance

My solution of this task is (i assume) time complexity O(N^2). Obviously my code is not handling well large arrays. How could I make this more efficient? What am I missing? Could you guys recommend some material that could help me understand how to write more efficient code in C? Thanks!

Task:

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.
>
> Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ..., A[N − 1].
>
> The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|
>
> In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> ```
>  A[0] = 3
>  A[1] = 1
>  A[2] = 2
>  A[3] = 4
>  A[4] = 3
> ```
>
> We can split this tape in four places:
>
> ```
> P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
> P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
> P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
> P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
> ```
>
> Write a function:
>
> ```
> int solution(int A[], int N);
> ```
>
> that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the minimal difference that can be achieved.
>
> For example, given:
>
> ```
>  A[0] = 3
>  A[1] = 1
>  A[2] = 2
>  A[3] = 4
>  A[4] = 3
> ```
>
> the function should return 1, as explained above.
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> - N is an integer within the range [2..100,000];
> - each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].

My solution:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int solution(int A[], int N) {
     
    uint32_t p = 1, i=0;
    int64_t lowestSum = 0, sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum = 0;
    
    
    {
        // iterate over all possible values of P
        for(p=1; p<N; p++)
        {
            sum1 = 0;
            sum2 = 0;
    
            for(i=0; i<N; i++)
            {
                if(i<p)
                {
                    sum1 += A[i];
                }
                else 
                {
                    sum2 += A[i];
                }
            }
    
            sum = abs(sum1 - sum2);
    
            //if this is the first iteration, 
            //initialize the lowest sum with current sum
            if(p==1)
            {
                lowestSum = sum;
            }
            else if(lowestSum > sum)
            {
                lowestSum = sum;
            }        
        }
    }

    return lowestSum;
}
```

Comment: You should be able to do this in O(n). Parse the input array, writing the running total to another array `int64_t left[N]`. You now know the whole `total`. Parse the new array. The sum of the right-side is `total - left[i]`. You can now figure the minimal absolute difference.

Comment: Can't you achieve an O(N) solution (with O(N) extra space)? If you calculate the cumulative sum going forward in one array, the cumulative sum working backwards in a second array (both O(N) operations in terms of time and space), and then scan over the pair of arrays to find the minimal absolute difference between corresponding cumulative sums — also an O(N) operation.  I've not worked this through, but something along these lines should work, I think.

Comment: @WeatherVane — great minds think alike!

Comment: Guys this is probably it. How do you come up with these solutions just like that? I am supposed to take a test for a job interview and I am really scared that I wont have these great ideas like you guys.

Comment: In fact, if the original array can a large enough type, and if the data is being read from a stream, there is no need for another array, or to store the original values, only the running total. Good luck with the interview!

Comment: @Slav3k — apart from accumulated anno domini (aka years of experience), I've read a lot of books about programming and algorithms.  This problem reminds me of a loosely similar problem in one of Jon Bentley's books — either "Programming Pearls" or "More Programming Pearls".  That one was for the largest sum in a contiguous set of elements of an array (some positive, some negative; it's boring if they're all positive).  Knowing about that, I was able to guess at a possible solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The data constraints show that the maximum sum of the inputs is `100000 * 1000 = 100000000` which can fit a 32-bit `int`.

I suggest that if the data is coming from a stream, all you need is to store the running sum of the values in a first pass, and figure out the answer in a second pass.

This is **O(N)**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *left = malloc(n * sizeof *left);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int val;
        scanf("%d", &val);
        sum += val;
        left[i] = sum;
    }
        
    int mindiff = INT_MAX;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int right = sum - left[i];
        int diff = abs(left[i] - right);
        if(diff < mindiff) {
            mindiff = diff;
        }
    }
    printf("mindiff = %d\n", mindiff);
    free(left);
    return 0;
}
```

For the specified input

```
5
3 1 2 4 3
```

The output is

```
mindiff = 1
```

I realise the program is devoid of any error checking, which isn't great, but it does show the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Based on advices provided by Weather Vane and  Jonathan Leffler I was able to comeup with this solution, which was given 100% result. The lesson learned is to simply try avoid O(N^2) solutions at any cost. I wish I could train my mind to see these solutions (faster).

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int solution(int A[], int N) {
    
    int64_t LeftRight[N], sum = 0;
    int64_t lowest_diff = 0, diff = 0;
    uint32_t i = 0;
    

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum += A[i];
        LeftRight[i] = sum;
    }

    sum = 0;
    i = N - 1;

    while(i > 0)
    {
        sum += A[i];
        diff = abs(LeftRight[i-1]-sum);
        //is this first elemnt on the right?
        if(i == (N-1))
        {
            lowest_diff = diff;
        }
        else if(lowest_diff > diff)
        {
            lowest_diff = diff;
        }        
        i--;
    }

    return lowest_diff;
}
```

Comment: Well done.  Be cautious about the `int64_t LeftRight[N]` inside the function.  With up to 100,000 numbers in the array, you might need 800,000 bytes on the stack for your array.  Granted, even on a Windows machine, the stack size defaults to 1 MiB, so there is room to spare (Unix machines typically provide 8 MiB of stack by default, so they have more room to spare), but you should be aware of the space you're using.  Using `malloc()` is safer, but fiddlier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some fairly fancy code I developed, but the core algorithm uses O(1) space and O(N) time for the analysis, making just 2 passes over the data.

This program takes an optional `-v` argument to print a verbose analysis of its working.  It uses my normal error handling code which is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  I find that it makes error handling much easier, so I'm more inclined to actually do the necessary error checking.  It checks that the input meets the conditions and reports errors (and bails out) if the data is invalid.  It adapts the detailed layout of the verbose data to keep columns aligned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "stderr.h"

static const char optstr[] = "vh";
static const char usestr[] = "[-vh]";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -h  Print this help message and exit\n"
    "  -v  Print details of calculation as it is done\n"
    ;

static int solution(int A[], int N);

static int vflag = 0;
static int n_width = 0;
static int s_width = 0;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);

    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'v':
            vflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /*NOTREACHED*/
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc)
        err_usage(usestr);

    int N;
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1)
        err_error("failed to read array size\n");
    if (N < 2 || N > 100000)
        err_error("array size %d out of range 2..100,000\n", N);

    /* VLA - but size was checked and won't overflow stack */
    int array[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &array[i]) != 1)
            err_error("failed to read element %d of array\n", i);
        if (array[i] < -1000 || array[i] > +1000)
            err_error("element %d (%d) is out of range -1000..+1000\n", i, array[i]);
    }

    n_width = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", N - 1);
    s_width = snprintf(0, 0, "%d", (N - 1) * -1000);

    int result = solution(array, N);

    printf("result: %d\n", result);
    return 0;
}

static inline int abs_diff(int a, int b)
{
    return abs(a - b);
}

static int solution(int A[], int N)
{
    int total = 0;

    /* First pass over array - O(N) */
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        total += A[i];

    if (vflag)
        printf("N = %d; total = %d\n", N, total);

    /* Second pass over array - O(N) */
    int lhs = A[0];
    int min_gap = abs_diff(lhs, total - lhs);
    if (vflag)
    {
        printf("A[%*d] = %5d: lhs = %*d, rhs = %*d, |lhs - rhs| = %*d ** minimum so far\n",
               n_width, 0, A[0], s_width, lhs, s_width, total - lhs,
               s_width, abs_diff(lhs, total - lhs));
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        lhs += A[i];
        int diff = abs_diff(lhs, total - lhs);
        if (vflag)
        {
            const char *marker = (diff < min_gap) ? " ** minimum so far" : "";
            printf("A[%*d] = %5d: lhs = %*d, rhs = %*d, |lhs - rhs| = %*d%s\n",
                   n_width, i, A[i], s_width, lhs, s_width, total - lhs,
                   s_width, abs_diff(lhs, total - lhs), marker);
        }
        if (diff < min_gap)
            min_gap = diff;
    }

    return min_gap;
}
```

For the sample data in the question, the verbose output is:

```
N = 5; total = 13
A[0] =     3: lhs =     3, rhs =    10, |lhs - rhs| =     7 ** minimum so far
A[1] =     1: lhs =     4, rhs =     9, |lhs - rhs| =     5 ** minimum so far
A[2] =     2: lhs =     6, rhs =     7, |lhs - rhs| =     1 ** minimum so far
A[3] =     4: lhs =    10, rhs =     3, |lhs - rhs| =     7
A[4] =     3: lhs =    13, rhs =     0, |lhs - rhs| =    13
result: 1
```

Note that there is one more line of output than the analysis in the question shows.

For a 20-line random input, I got:

```
N = 20; total = 973
A[ 0] =  -360: lhs =   -360, rhs =   1333, |lhs - rhs| =   1693 ** minimum so far
A[ 1] =  -675: lhs =  -1035, rhs =   2008, |lhs - rhs| =   3043
A[ 2] =   245: lhs =   -790, rhs =   1763, |lhs - rhs| =   2553
A[ 3] =    47: lhs =   -743, rhs =   1716, |lhs - rhs| =   2459
A[ 4] =  -100: lhs =   -843, rhs =   1816, |lhs - rhs| =   2659
A[ 5] =   987: lhs =    144, rhs =    829, |lhs - rhs| =    685 ** minimum so far
A[ 6] =    16: lhs =    160, rhs =    813, |lhs - rhs| =    653 ** minimum so far
A[ 7] =  -146: lhs =     14, rhs =    959, |lhs - rhs| =    945
A[ 8] =   126: lhs =    140, rhs =    833, |lhs - rhs| =    693
A[ 9] =  -541: lhs =   -401, rhs =   1374, |lhs - rhs| =   1775
A[10] =  -116: lhs =   -517, rhs =   1490, |lhs - rhs| =   2007
A[11] =   842: lhs =    325, rhs =    648, |lhs - rhs| =    323 ** minimum so far
A[12] =  -769: lhs =   -444, rhs =   1417, |lhs - rhs| =   1861
A[13] =  -361: lhs =   -805, rhs =   1778, |lhs - rhs| =   2583
A[14] =   295: lhs =   -510, rhs =   1483, |lhs - rhs| =   1993
A[15] =  -471: lhs =   -981, rhs =   1954, |lhs - rhs| =   2935
A[16] =   398: lhs =   -583, rhs =   1556, |lhs - rhs| =   2139
A[17] =   932: lhs =    349, rhs =    624, |lhs - rhs| =    275 ** minimum so far
A[18] =   270: lhs =    619, rhs =    354, |lhs - rhs| =    265 ** minimum so far
A[19] =   354: lhs =    973, rhs =      0, |lhs - rhs| =    973
result: 265
```

For a full 100,000 line input, the output started and ended like this:

```
N = 100000; total = -53534 
A[    0] =  -301: lhs =       -301, rhs =     -53233, |lhs - rhs| =      52932 ** minimum so far 
A[    1] =   338: lhs =         37, rhs =     -53571, |lhs - rhs| =      53608  
A[    2] =   -35: lhs =          2, rhs =     -53536, |lhs - rhs| =      53538  
A[    3] =   243: lhs =        245, rhs =     -53779, |lhs - rhs| =      54024  
A[    4] =  -537: lhs =       -292, rhs =     -53242, |lhs - rhs| =      52950  
A[    5] =   687: lhs =        395, rhs =     -53929, |lhs - rhs| =      54324  
A[    6] =   116: lhs =        511, rhs =     -54045, |lhs - rhs| =      54556  
A[    7] =  -257: lhs =        254, rhs =     -53788, |lhs - rhs| =      54042  
A[    8] =   288: lhs =        542, rhs =     -54076, |lhs - rhs| =      54618  
A[    9] =   592: lhs =       1134, rhs =     -54668, |lhs - rhs| =      55802  
A[   10] =  -385: lhs =        749, rhs =     -54283, |lhs - rhs| =      55032  
A[   11] =  -254: lhs =        495, rhs =     -54029, |lhs - rhs| =      54524  
A[   12] =   816: lhs =       1311, rhs =     -54845, |lhs - rhs| =      56156  
A[   13] =  -946: lhs =        365, rhs =     -53899, |lhs - rhs| =      54264  
A[   14] =  -477: lhs =       -112, rhs =     -53422, |lhs - rhs| =      53310  
A[   15] =   -61: lhs =       -173, rhs =     -53361, |lhs - rhs| =      53188  
A[   16] =   225: lhs =         52, rhs =     -53586, |lhs - rhs| =      53638  
A[   17] =   174: lhs =        226, rhs =     -53760, |lhs - rhs| =      53986  
A[   18] =  -269: lhs =        -43, rhs =     -53491, |lhs - rhs| =      53448  
A[   19] =  -408: lhs =       -451, rhs =     -53083, |lhs - rhs| =      52632 ** minimum so far 
A[   20] =   123: lhs =       -328, rhs =     -53206, |lhs - rhs| =      52878  
A[   21] =   124: lhs =       -204, rhs =     -53330, |lhs - rhs| =      53126  
A[   22] =  -364: lhs =       -568, rhs =     -52966, |lhs - rhs| =      52398 ** minimum so far 
A[   23] =    41: lhs =       -527, rhs =     -53007, |lhs - rhs| =      52480  
A[   24] =  -617: lhs =      -1144, rhs =     -52390, |lhs - rhs| =      51246 ** minimum so far 
A[   25] =   583: lhs =       -561, rhs =     -52973, |lhs - rhs| =      52412  
A[   26] =  -860: lhs =      -1421, rhs =     -52113, |lhs - rhs| =      50692 ** minimum so far 
A[   27] =    39: lhs =      -1382, rhs =     -52152, |lhs - rhs| =      50770  
A[   28] =   465: lhs =       -917, rhs =     -52617, |lhs - rhs| =      51700  
A[   29] =  -413: lhs =      -1330, rhs =     -52204, |lhs - rhs| =      50874  
A[   30] =  -530: lhs =      -1860, rhs =     -51674, |lhs - rhs| =      49814 ** minimum so far
…
A[18048] =   381: lhs =     -27278, rhs =     -26256, |lhs - rhs| =       1022
A[18049] =   510: lhs =     -26768, rhs =     -26766, |lhs - rhs| =          2 ** minimum so far
A[18050] =  -754: lhs =     -27522, rhs =     -26012, |lhs - rhs| =       1510
…
A[99990] =  -196: lhs =     -57461, rhs =       3927, |lhs - rhs| =      61388
A[99991] =   698: lhs =     -56763, rhs =       3229, |lhs - rhs| =      59992
A[99992] =  -141: lhs =     -56904, rhs =       3370, |lhs - rhs| =      60274
A[99993] =   907: lhs =     -55997, rhs =       2463, |lhs - rhs| =      58460
A[99994] =   158: lhs =     -55839, rhs =       2305, |lhs - rhs| =      58144
A[99995] =   563: lhs =     -55276, rhs =       1742, |lhs - rhs| =      57018
A[99996] =   851: lhs =     -54425, rhs =        891, |lhs - rhs| =      55316
A[99997] =   -12: lhs =     -54437, rhs =        903, |lhs - rhs| =      55340
A[99998] =   703: lhs =     -53734, rhs =        200, |lhs - rhs| =      53934
A[99999] =   200: lhs =     -53534, rhs =          0, |lhs - rhs| =      53534
result: 2
```

I have a convenient random number generator program that can be told to generate N integers between -1000 and +1000 inclusive (and a whole lot more, but that's all that was necessary for this testing).